# Error pushing changes on GIT. Ref names must follow git ref-format rules

Tags: git, git-branch, cherry-pick, remote-branch

I have one error using git on Sourcetree.
I've created a local branch called sprints/Mycompany_sprint_1 (because I want it in a category) and then I did multiple cherry picks to this branch from another one.
After that, I tried to push all the changes on my branch, but I am receiving next error:

> The Remote branch '' (Local branch = 'sprints/Mycompany_sprint-1') is invalid. Ref names must follow git ref-format rules:
> https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html
> Completed with errors, see above.

But if I go to the link, I am following (as far I saw) all the rules, because looking at the first rule:

> They can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no
> slash-separated component can begin with a dot . or end with the
> sequence .lock.

I check if the problem could be that the spring category already exists, but is not the case.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, please? I'm affraid that cannot see the error here...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This seems to be a bug affecting SourceTree for Windows version 3.3.4: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-12593

A workaround until the bug is fixed is to untick and retick the branch checkbox in the push dialog.

Comment: Note that sometimes SourceTree is not updating automagically, like happened to me and others, so I had to download and reinstall from Bitbucket Site [Ref SRCTREEWIN-12593](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-12593?error=login_required&error_description=Login+required&state=997a8b3e-036e-435e-9658-c0c8d7eaaba5)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your *local* branch name.  The problem is with the branch name you asked the *other* Git to use.

Here's that error message again, this time in fixed-width font for clarity:

> ```
> The Remote branch '' (Local branch = 'sprints/Mycompany_sprint-1') is invalid.
> ```

Remove the parenthetical remark, which is merely informational:

> ```
> The Remote branch '' is invalid.
> ```

You have—somehow; this should be impossible—specified a remote branch name that is completely empty.  That's not a valid branch name.  How you specified it, I have no idea, but you need to stop doing that.

Comment: Dammit, I didn't understand it at first. Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I am not defining an empty name, I am using the same... not sure about the failure. Anyway, I pushed through console and it works properly

Comment: Yeah, the command line won't let you supply an empty destination name without at least working at it. This sounds like a GUI bug.

Answer (score 2):

As per 22nd of November 2019 this finally seems to be fixed.

```
SourceTree 3.3.6 [22 November 2019]
  Changes
    Fixed new branches in the push dialog not setting the remote branch name
    Fixed the create patch screen allowing split view
```

Source: [SourceTree Release Notes](https://product-downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/ga/ReleaseNotes_3.3.6.html)

Comment: I'm afraid that is not fixing yet. I tested with that version and newer ones and it is continue appearing sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

I was Pushing Release_Staging_2.0 to orgin I was getting same error..When I renamed it to Staging_2.0 in my local branch ,it worked..Still didnt find exact reason but u can try.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in SourceTree when trying to push a detached HEAD (from a tag) to a different repository. It was not any name format validation error.

The solution was create a local branch from the HEAD and push it to the different repo.